# WLAN transmitter emit power

Tags: wireless-networking

A transmitter that emits 50 mW signal is connected to a cable with 3 dB loss. If the cable is connected to an antenna with 9 dBi gain, what is the EIRP at the antenna element?

Answer (score 0):

50mW is 17dBm. Subtract 3 for the cable loss and add 9 for the antenna's directional gain and your answer is 23dBm (200mW).